# How to count clicks of a link and store in database(Django)?

Tags: python, django

How do I edit this code to count the times the "Link" was clicked and add this to the database model "T_shirt" in a new column?

HTML

```
<ul class="products">
{% for v in owner_obj %}
    <div class="container">
    <a href={{ v.Link }} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <img src={{ v.Images }} width="150" height="150">
    </a>

    <figcaption>  {{ v.Titles }} </figcaption>
    <figcaption> <b>{{ v.Prices }} </b></figcaption>
</div>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Models.py

```
class T_shirt(models.Model):
    Images = models.ImageField()
    Titles = models.CharField(max_length=250, primary_key=True)
    Prices = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Link = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a model thats called clickcounter. Give it two fields 1. url(charfield) 2. counter (IntegerField).
Make a function with 1 parameter for url. exampfunc(url).
In that function check if the url already exist and update the counter with +1 otherwise create a new object.

You would define this function in every view you would like to count the urls of. This is one way, there always are better ways. But you need to start somewhere right ?